# How do I design a table with multiple detail rows in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using iReport to design the following table:

```
| project | value1     |
| company | value2     |
| client  | value3     |

| project | value4     |
| company | value5     |
| client  | value6     |
```

Here `project, company, client` are row "headers" and the whole group should repeat.

I.e all three rows should be repeated and filled with proper values. So far I was able to create a table where only one detail row repeats.

How can I design this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use a subreport as a workaround.
Left only a single detail band there with no headers or footers and text fields to construct the table I wanted. Had to play a little with positioning and resizing to make hte table stretch the way it should